# How to find number of working days for a month?

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel sheet I have a date (October,2018).

From this I have to populate start date and end date of that month and number of working days in another column.

Answer (score 0):

the format you're looking for would be something like this: [reference](https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-format-date/)

```
Range("C5") = Format(date_example, "mmm-yy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub DateTest()

    'convert the cell to text format and prints the date
    Range("C5").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("C5") = Format(#10/18/2018#, "mmm-yy")

    'gets the no of days between two dates
    MsgBox "No of days : " & DateDiff("d", #1/1/2019#, Date, vbMonday)

    'gets the no of working days between two dates
    MsgBox "No of working days : " & WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(#1/1/2019#, Date)

End Sub
```